# KendoUI grid checkbox column

Tags: asp.net, razor, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Currently I am having this code for displaying a KendoUI grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CleverFit.Models.MyHistorie>()
      .Name("grid")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource // Configure the grid data source
          .Ajax() // Specify that ajax binding is used
          .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Action")) // Set the action method which will return the data in JSON format
       )
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
        columns.Bound(product => product.Datum).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}");
        columns.Bound(product => product.Aktion);
        columns.Bound(product => product.Ergebnis);
        columns.Bound(product => product.Wiedervorlage).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy H:mm}");
        columns.Bound(product => product.Bemerkung);
        columns.Bound(product => product.Erledigt);
      })
      .Pageable() // Enable paging
      .Sortable() // Enable sorting
)
```

I tried already this:

```
columns.Bound(product => product.Erledigt).ClientTemplate(
    "<input type='checkbox' value='#= ProductID #' " +
        "# if (Enabled) { #" +
            "checked='checked'" +
        "# } #" +
    "/>"
);
```

But if I add this, there is no data displayed in the grid...

The values of the last column which is `product.Erledigt` are displayed as true or false. Is it possible to display them as checkboxes?

I am using Telerik KendoUI and loading the content of the template via AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following FAQ page:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-to-display-checkboxes-in-ajax-bound-grids

In addition, you can make the checkbox readonly or disabled to prevent the user from editing it and expect the changes to be persisted.

**Update**

The code that you have tried contains two data field values, which obviously do not exist in your Grid: `ProductID` and `Enabled`. Most probably you are getting a JavaScript error in the browser console. Replace `Enabled` with `Erledigt` and remove `value='#= ProductID #'` if you don't need such a thing.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but if I add exact the same code, the grid is not displaying any data

Comment: Perfect that did it!

Comment: do you also know how to disable it from editing? I would prefer to do it with Kendo (HtmlHelper) and not the html from ClientTemplate